# Getting Matched HTML Value with Regex

Tags: c#, html, regex

Ok to start I know i should not be using Regex to parse HTML as it's not very reliable, not 100% safe, etc. However, this is just a learning excercise for regex as much as anything else.

So my example uses the bbc website http://www.bbc.co.uk/sport/football/premier-league/table.

The project is parsing the tbody of the first table. I am trying to do a search so that only the elements matching a search value are returned. For example, given the search "manc" i would want the tr tag for manchester city and manchester united (matched from the url).

What i have so far is `<tr\b[^>]*>(.*?)manc(.*?)</tr>` however this matches from the first tr to the closing tr after man city and then returns the expected result for man utd. Could anyone point out where i've gone wrong with this regex.

**Edit: Source (Trimmed)**

```
<tbody id="trc-20-118996114-3">
  <tr id="team-138824012" class="team first">
    <td class="statistics"></td>
    <td class='position'>
      <span class='moving-up'>Moving up</span>
      <span class='position-number'>1</span>
    </td>
    <td class="team-name">
      <a href='http://www.bbc.co.uk/sport/football/teams/arsenal'>Arsenal</a>
    </td>
    <td class="played">0</td>

    <td class="home-won">
      <span>0</span>
    </td>
    <td class="home-drawn">0</td>
    <td class="home-lost">0</td>
    <td class="home-for">0</td>
    <td class="home-against">0</td>
    <td class="away-won">
      <span>0</span>
    </td>
    <td class="away-drawn">0</td>
    <td class="away-lost">0</td>
    <td class="away-for">0</td>
    <td class="away-against">0</td>
    <td class="goal-difference">0</td>
    <td class="points">0</td>
    <td class="last-10-games">
      <ol>
        <li class="win" title="Win">
          <span>Win</span>
        </li>
        <li class="draw" title="Draw">
          <span>Draw</span>
        </li>
        <li class="draw" title="Draw">
          <span>Draw</span>
        </li>
        <li class="draw" title="Draw">
          <span>Draw</span>
        </li>
        <li class="loss" title="Loss">
          <span>Loss</span>
        </li>
        <li class="win" title="Win">
          <span>Win</span>
        </li>
        <li class="win" title="Win">
          <span>Win</span>
        </li>
        <li class="loss" title="Loss">
          <span>Loss</span>
        </li>
        <li class="win" title="Win">
          <span>Win</span>
        </li>
        <li class="win last" title="Win">
          <span>Win</span>
        </li>
      </ol>
    </td>
    <td class="status">
      <a class="report" href="http://www.bbc.co.uk/sport/0/football/17973141">Report</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="team-137316633" class="team">
    <td class="statistics"></td>
    <td class='position'>
      <span class='moving-up'>Moving up</span>
      <span class='position-number'>2</span>
    </td>
    <td class="team-name">
      <a href='http://www.bbc.co.uk/sport/football/teams/aston-villa'>Aston Villa</a>
    </td>
    <td class="played">0</td>

    <td class="home-won">
      <span>0</span>
    </td>
    <td class="home-drawn">0</td>
    <td class="home-lost">0</td>
    <td class="home-for">0</td>
    <td class="home-against">0</td>
    <td class="away-won">
      <span>0</span>
    </td>
    <td class="away-drawn">0</td>
    <td class="away-lost">0</td>
    <td class="away-for">0</td>
    <td class="away-against">0</td>
    <td class="goal-difference">0</td>
    <td class="points">0</td>
    <td class="last-10-games">
      <ol>
        <li class="loss" title="Loss">
          <span>Loss</span>
        </li>
        <li class="draw" title="Draw">
          <span>Draw</span>
        </li>
        <li class="draw" title="Draw">
          <span>Draw</span>
        </li>
        <li class="loss" title="Loss">
          <span>Loss</span>
        </li>
        <li class="draw" title="Draw">
          <span>Draw</span>
        </li>
        <li class="loss" title="Loss">
          <span>Loss</span>
        </li>
        <li class="draw" title="Draw">
          <span>Draw</span>
        </li>
        <li class="draw" title="Draw">
          <span>Draw</span>
        </li>
        <li class="loss" title="Loss">
          <span>Loss</span>
        </li>
        <li class="loss last" title="Loss">
          <span>Loss</span>
        </li>
      </ol>
    </td>
    <td class="status">
      <a class="report" href="http://www.bbc.co.uk/sport/0/football/17973120">Report</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="team-137318151" class="team">
    <td class="statistics"></td>
    <td class='position'>
      <span class='moving-down'>Moving down</span>
      <span class='position-number'>7</span>
    </td>
    <td class="team-name">
      <a href='http://www.bbc.co.uk/sport/football/teams/manchester-city'>Man City</a>
    </td>
    <td class="played">0</td>

    <td class="home-won">
      <span>0</span>
    </td>
    <td class="home-drawn">0</td>
    <td class="home-lost">0</td>
    <td class="home-for">0</td>
    <td class="home-against">0</td>
    <td class="away-won">
      <span>0</span>
    </td>
    <td class="away-drawn">0</td>
    <td class="away-lost">0</td>
    <td class="away-for">0</td>
    <td class="away-against">0</td>
    <td class="goal-difference">0</td>
    <td class="points">0</td>
    <td class="last-10-games">
      <ol>
        <li class="win" title="Win">
          <span>Win</span>
        </li>
        <li class="win" title="Win">
          <span>Win</span>
        </li>
        <li class="win" title="Win">
          <span>Win</span>
        </li>
        <li class="win" title="Win">
          <span>Win</span>
        </li>
        <li class="win" title="Win">
          <span>Win</span>
        </li>
        <li class="win" title="Win">
          <span>Win</span>
        </li>
        <li class="loss" title="Loss">
          <span>Loss</span>
        </li>
        <li class="draw" title="Draw">
          <span>Draw</span>
        </li>
        <li class="draw" title="Draw">
          <span>Draw</span>
        </li>
        <li class="win last" title="Win">
          <span>Win</span>
        </li>
      </ol>
    </td>
    <td class="status">
      <a class="report" href="http://www.bbc.co.uk/sport/0/football/17973148">Report</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="team-137318152" class="team">
    <td class="statistics"></td>
    <td class='position'>
      <span class='moving-down'>Moving down</span>
      <span class='position-number'>8</span>
    </td>
    <td class="team-name">
      <a href='http://www.bbc.co.uk/sport/football/teams/manchester-united'>Man Utd</a>
    </td>
    <td class="played">0</td>

    <td class="home-won">
      <span>0</span>
    </td>
    <td class="home-drawn">0</td>
    <td class="home-lost">0</td>
    <td class="home-for">0</td>
    <td class="home-against">0</td>
    <td class="away-won">
      <span>0</span>
    </td>
    <td class="away-drawn">0</td>
    <td class="away-lost">0</td>
    <td class="away-for">0</td>
    <td class="away-against">0</td>
    <td class="goal-difference">0</td>
    <td class="points">0</td>
    <td class="last-10-games">
      <ol>
        <li class="win" title="Win">
          <span>Win</span>
        </li>
        <li class="win" title="Win">
          <span>Win</span>
        </li>
        <li class="loss" title="Loss">
          <span>Loss</span>
        </li>
        <li class="draw" title="Draw">
          <span>Draw</span>
        </li>
        <li class="win" title="Win">
          <span>Win</span>
        </li>
        <li class="loss" title="Loss">
          <span>Loss</span>
        </li>
        <li class="win" title="Win">
          <span>Win</span>
        </li>
        <li class="win" title="Win">
          <span>Win</span>
        </li>
        <li class="win" title="Win">
          <span>Win</span>
        </li>
        <li class="win last" title="Win">
          <span>Win</span>
        </li>
      </ol>
    </td>
    <td class="status">
      <a class="report" href="http://www.bbc.co.uk/sport/0/football/17973162">Report</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: Why the downvote :(? Need to learn for future reference

Comment: Not sure. Maybe because parsing HTML-with-RegEx is a very frequently occurring question. In most cases, one need a DOM Parser, such as JavaScript's [DOMParser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOMParser) instead of fiddling with a HTML string through a Regexp. Instead of linking to a volatile site, can you include the relevant part(s) of the source code in your question? In that way, the question remains relevant, even when BBC decides to remove that page.

Comment: @RobW Added a trimmed version of the source

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is, your regular expression is too broad. Look what you're asking for:

```
<tr\b[^>]*>(.*?)manc(.*?)</tr>
```

Lets simplify it a little bit.

```
<tr>.*?manc.*?</tr>
```

So you're saying, ok. I need to match a tr followed by *anything* and then manc and then ANYTHING and then a closing tr. So. Of course what happens is the regex starts at the first tr and goes ok. I've got a tr let me keep matching until I find manc. In the meantime, you probably just passed a bunch of *other* tr. But your regex doesn't care.

Try this:

```
<tr>(?:(?!</tr>).)*manc.+?</tr>
```

Or, I guess in your example:

```
<tr\b[^>]*>(?:(?!</tr>).)*manc.+?</tr>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, it's working for manc, is there any way that if no search is specified (so `<tr\b[^>]*>(?:(?!</tr>).)*.+?</tr>`) it would return all results. At the moment i'm finding that when running like that, the first two tr elements are returned as a single match

Comment: Well that one really is simple: <tr\b[^>]*>.+?</tr>

Comment: sorry meant is it possible in one regex?

Comment: You mean you can't have an if-else statement that picks a regex?

Comment: Well...I don't think you can. It doesn't really make any sense. In one case you're saying match ANY TR, and in another you are saying match a TR that looks like this. If you combine them with an alternation operator, well, you're always going to match anything. I get the point of learning exercises, but sometimes the learning exercise should tell you when you *shouldn't* try something. :)

Answer (score 0):

REGEX is ill-suited to this because it is not designed to be a parser. Except where the circumstances are very forgiving, and particularly in JavaScript (which has a fairly primitive REGEX implementation) it cannot hope to ascertain with certainty which opening tags match which closing tags.

Firstly, we need to use `[\s\S]` rather than `.` because the latter does not work multi-line as it does not match white-space characters, and the HTML of the table you mention is on multiple lines. The former will, since it is a range that matches everything spacial and non-spacial - i.e. everything ever.

With this in mind, you might be tempted to do this:

```
/<tr\b[^>]*?>[\s\S]*?manc[\s\S]*?<\/tr>/gi
```

...i.e. get all rows that mention the string 'manc'.

Take the following, simplified HTML:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Notts County</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Manchester United</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Arsenal</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

...the above pattern will match

```
<tr>
    <td>Notts County</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Manchester United</td>
</tr>
```

This is logical. The REGEX pattern starts at the beginning, finds the opening `tr` (Notts County) and is asked whether, after an indeterminate number of optional characters, the string "Manc" is found. It is.

The problem, of course, is that, in finding "Manc", it has unwittingly wandered over a `tr` boundary into the next row, since our `[\s\S]*?` pattern allowed it to.

We cannot prevent this because REGEX does not allow you to negate sequences - only characters from a range (except in the case of negative look-ahead and look-behind assertions).

In short, by all means learn REGEX, but you've picked a difficult string to begin with :)